# How are Windows API calls made on Assembly Level?

Tags: winapi, assembly

I've written some high level interpreters and a simple byte code compiler and interpreter and I want to start making a powerful intermediate language for my small operating system.

It has its own API just like windows does, and the only thing which prevents me of starting this project is to know how these specific API calls (for example the win32 forms api) are being made on the assembly level.

Is there a way to see the assembly output of not optimized c code for example and look how exatly the calls are being made? Or any sources on the WWW?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take debugger and go :)

Comment: The Win32 API is nothing more than a set of DLL functions and COM interfaces. APIs like .NET Forms are built on top of that foundation. Do you know how to make regular function calls in assembly? Do you understand how the call stack works? DLL function calls and interface method calls are just like regular function calls, and they setup the call stack the same way, you just have to use a runtime pointer to obtain the memory address of the function/method to `call`, whether that be from your app's DLL lookup table that the OS loader populates at app startup, or from an object's vtable, etc.

Comment: You need to distnguish between system calls and Windows API calls. If you're writing your own operating system you will be writing system calls, not Windows API calls, so it is system calls that you need to know about.

Answer (score 6):

Having C documentation for the API, and knowing the calling convention / ABI, should be enough to create asm that uses it.  There's no "magic" needed (no inline `syscall` instructions or anything like that).

---

Much of the Win32 API is implemented in user-space DLLs, so API calls are no different from other library function calls.  (i.e. an indirect CALL with a function pointer, if I recall correctly).

Often the library function implementation will involve a `syscall` to interact with the kernel (or for 32-bit code, maybe an `int` or `sysenter`, I'm not sure), but this interface is not documented and is not stable across different Windows versions.

Comment: Most of the interfaces are documented unofficially, but some came from sources like the Windows DDKs etc. Prior to XP system calls were usually through `int`, Starting with XP it was via `sysenter`, and with x64 versions of Windows via `syscall`.

Comment: I should have said Windows XP supported `sysenter` but as I recall, on systems without `sysenter` support it would use `int`